# Android:How to save values in EditText when returning to an Activity

Tags: java, android, savestate

I am trying to save values entered to a form so that when a user returns to the activity the content entered remains populated. As it functions now. The user can enter details and click the "send button". The the next activity will then show details of what the user entered. If the user selects the "back button", the user returns the previous activity but the content is wiped from the fields in the form. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public final static String EXTRA_FROM = "com.example.assignment1.FROM";
     public final static String EXTRA_TO = "com.example.assignment1.TO";
     public final static String EXTRA_CC = "com.example.assignment1.CC";
     public final static String EXTRA_SUBJECT = "com.example.assignment1.SUBJECT";
     public final static String EXTRA_COMPOSE = "com.example.assignment1.COMPOSE";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
        outState.putString(EXTRA_FROM, from);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)
    {
        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        String from = savedState.getString(EXTRA_FROM);
        emailFrom.setText(from);
    }
    public void emailSend (View sendButton) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayEmailActivity.class);
        EditText emailFrom =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom);
        EditText emailTo =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
        EditText emailCc =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCc);
        EditText emailSubject =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailSubject);
        EditText emailCompose =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCompose);

        String from = emailFrom.getText().toString();
        String to = emailTo.getText().toString();
        String cc = emailCc.getText().toString();
        String subject = emailSubject.getText().toString();
        String compose = emailCompose.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM,from);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TO,to);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CC,cc);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPOSE,compose);

        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void emailClear (View clearButton) {
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailFrom)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCc)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailBcc)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailSubject)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmailCompose)).setText("");  
    }

}
```

Second Activity......

```
public class DisplayEmailActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_email);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String from = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_FROM);
        String to = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_TO);
        String cc = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_CC);
        String subject = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
        String compose = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_COMPOSE);


        TextView textFrom =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailFrom);
        TextView textTo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailTo);
        TextView textCc =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailCc);
        TextView textSubject =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailSubject);
        TextView textCompose =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayEmailCompose);

        textFrom.setText(from);
        textTo.setText(to);
        textCc.setText(cc);
        textSubject.setText(subject);
        textCompose.setText(compose);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_email, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void emailBack (View backButton){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        startActivity (intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: Store its value in SharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the method like this,

```
public void emailBack (View backButton){

    onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I am glad it helped. But help us with your credit by starting to accept the answers which has helped you so far. You have to click on the tick mark that you will find below the total votes counter on the left side of each answer.

Comment: You should not call `onBackPressed()`, the system does that when you press back. You want to call `finnish()` which is what the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` does.

Comment: is there any rule being passed which says that I shouldn't call onBackPressed()? And if it is going to be used by the system why is it public then? I wanted the user to clearly understand what it means to travel back to the previous activity without losing data. I don't find anything wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to save entries made into the form before they are sent. So if the application is killed, whatever entries the user made are saved up to the point of the application ending?

Comment: @Andro you should not call the callbacks. They are public because the system should be able to call them in your packages. What you want to do is to finish the activity, right? If you call the callback to end the activity you depend on its implementation and that is not a good thing to do. You could even choose to handle the back key differently in your app and then break emailBack.

As for saving, SharedPreferences is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

`emailBack` starts a whole new activity. just call `finish` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared preferences... To create a String value use -

```
String string12 = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("butname12", " ");
```

And if you want to change it or rewrite -

```
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit()
                    .putString("butname12", "0" )
                    .commit();
```

To call the meaning of saved value -

```
String ss = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("butname12", " ");
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of preferences